# Directly call C++ struct constructor from cython

Tags: python, struct, cython

I'm trying to wrap some C++ code that uses structs with constructors, and not figuring out how.

C++ Struct:

```
typedef struct point_3d_t
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    point_3d_t(double x, double y, double z)
        : x(x)
        , y(y)
        , z(z)
        {}

} point_3d;
```

Cython wrapper:

```
cdef extern from "./cppdar.hpp":
    ctypedef struct point_3d:
        point_3d(double, double, double)
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
```

Now, I'd *expect* to be able to construct the struct via something like `cdef point_3d p1(v, v, v)` (from within the cython file), but I can't seem to figure out how to get cython to just use the provided constructor.

I've tried:

- `cdef point_3d p1(v, v, v)`
- `cdef point_3d p1 = point_3d(v, v, v)`
- `cdef point_3d p1(0, 0, 0)`
- `cdef point_3d p1 = point_3d(0, 0, 0)`

Where `v` is a explicit `cdef double v = 0`, but none work.

Using plain `cdef point_3d p1`, `p1.x = nnnn`, etc..., but that's annoying, and I don't see why I shouldn't be able to use the default constructor, I think.

Trying to research the issue yields a lot of clutter related to class constructors, which hasn't been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is you can't stack-allocate C++ objects with constructor arguments in cython, basically *at all*:

From: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/fuKd-nQLpBs

> Yes, it's a limitation, but it's a more fundamental issue than the 
>   parser. The construction and destruction of stack-allocated objects in
>   C++ is intricately tied to their scope, and scoping rules are 
>   different in Python and C. For example, consider
>
> ```
> if some_condition(): 
>     x = Foo(1) 
> else: 
>     x = Foo(2, 3) 
> return x.method()
> ```
>
> This simply can't be expressed as such in C++. Conversely
>
> ```
> if (some_other_condition()) { 
>     Foo_with_RIAA foo(x) 
> } 
> ...
> ```
>
> wouldn't translate "correctly" Python scoping rules.
>
> Now there are some cases where it could make sense, but significant 
>   code generation changes would have to be made, as currently all 
>   variables are declared at the top of a function (to follow the C89 
>   standard, which some compilers enforce) but in C++ mode we would have 
>   to defer the declaration of the variable to it's instantiation 
>   (including avoiding any automatically inserted C-level {} scopes used 
>   for simplicity in code generation).
>
> As one can always allocate such complicated objects on the heap, this 
>   isn't a significant limitation.

This is extra-double-plus annoying, because it means you simply *cannot* wrap classes that lack default constructors in many cases.

---

The horrible, no-good hacky workaround is to wrap the constructors in a simple C(++) function, and then expose *that* via cython.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your workround gets you? You still need a default constructor to be available I think.

Comment: @DavidW - Yeah, you still get a construct, construct&move process, but it's a hell of a lot better then instantiating as default, and then setting members individually.

Comment: I believe Cython can do construct then copy assignment/move assignment: `cdef point_3d p` then later `p=point_3d(...)`. You might need to tell it about the default constructor as well as the one you use.

Comment: @DavidW - Yeah, but I'm trying to delete the default-constructor, because I want to be able to avoid ever having an accidentally uninitialized instance.